# How to parallelize regularization loss calculation on multiple GPUs using pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

After wrapping my model in DataParallel

```
model20 = FourLayerConvNetWithPool()
model20 = nn.DataParallel(model20)
```

I can see utilization of all available GPUs. But after closer inspection noticed that "cuda:0" still has higher utilization (and as a result is a bottleneck {potentially minor for huge networks}).

Here is a snippet of training iteration:

```
model.train()  # put model to training mode
x = x.to(device=self.device, dtype=self.dtype)  # move to device, e.g. GPU
y = y.to(device=self.device, dtype=torch.long)

scores = model(x)
loss = F.cross_entropy(scores, y)

if (reg > 0):
    l2_regularization = torch.tensor(0).to(device=self.device, dtype=self.dtype)
    for param in model.parameters():
        l2_regularization += torch.norm(param, 2)
    loss += reg * l2_regularization

# Zero out all of the gradients for the variables which the optimizer
# will update.
optimizer.zero_grad()

# This is the backwards pass: compute the gradient of the loss with
# respect to each  parameter of the model.
loss.backward()

# Actually update the parameters of the model using the gradients
# computed by the backwards pass.
optimizer.step()
```

By commenting various parts of above snippet found that F.cross_entropy and torch.norm contribute to the difference between "cuda:0" and "cuda:1". This makes sense because these parts are not parallelized.

I understand that I can move F.cross_entropy to my model interface.

But what can be done with L2 regularization loss?

Comment: For L2 regularization, you can use the weight decay parameter in your optimizer, instead of implementing it manually.

Comment: Good point. But how to parallelize optimizer then?

Comment: The forward and backward prop computation will be parallelized (as you have put your model in DataParallel), but the loss is computed on only one GPU and so is the weight updates. So, I believe you can't parallelize the optimizer as such, since the optimizer only updates the weights. But, your actual gradient computations (in the backprop) are already parallelized. You can look in [this link](https://erickguan.me/2019/pytorch-parallel-model), the parallelization process is explained pictorially. It shows clearly which computations are done on multi-GPU and which are done on single GPU.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that both forward and backward are already parallelized, can see it (if I remove cross-entropy and L2 regularization then GPUs get exactly even load). The question is how to parallelize L2 regularization.

Comment: Have you tried to use the weight decay parameter instead of your manual implementation? What result does it give? I currently don't have access to a multi-GPU system, so I can't check for you.

Comment: On models where 4 GPUs start to make a difference (290 sec on 1 GPU vs. 105 sec on 4 GPU) I didn't notice a difference in performance from whether I'm doing L2 regularization or not.

Comment: Thank you @akshayk07 for pointing a weight decay parameter!

Comment: So, did it solve your issue or not? If yes, I'll add all this as an answer and this question can be closed as such.

Comment: Let me try again on small network tomorrow.

Comment: @ZakiMa did you have a chance to test this theory?